# vagrant up throwing error after configuring and enabling network interfaces

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

I have installed vagrant and virtual-box added homestead box on it now i am executing a command from terminal "vagrant up" which throws error here is snapshot:

[image: Snapshot of error]

I have installed virtual-box is 5.0 and vagrant is 1.8.1. I am totally stuck here. I don't know what should i do now? I am new to unubtu 16.04. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Pretty sure it's related to this change: https://tuxdiary.com/2015/10/28/persistent-network-interface-names-ubuntu/. It's created trouble all over the place. No idea how to solve ithere, though.

Comment: or [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/homestead-error) try upgrading to vagrant 1.8.4